# Facebook like in wordpress something broken

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

I am getting an error with my Facebook likes when using share this plugin or any facebook like script with my theme

[image]

[Here](http://pastebin.com/8nhU4tDg) is my `style.css`.

Can you please tell me what to edit or remove?
Maybe `overflow:hidden`?

Answer (score 0):

The same happened with me but automatically fixed in 2 weeks.
or try to delete cache and cookies it also happens due to incomplete loading a cache and cookies

Comment: its hapening from more than 1 months

Comment: hi guess i got it for www.modished.com                                       http://wordpress.org/support/topic/facebook-like-popup-flyout-cut-off?replies=8

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly CSS issue. I bet you have styled `<li>` element that holds FB like item as `overflow:hidden`. As you suggested. Please drop the site's url, so I could look into it.